# Confused about how to change the type of a function

Tags: ocaml

I am writing a small parser combinator library, currently I am implementing a mapping function that's able to change the contents of the result of a successfully applied combinator

```ml
let pmap mapper p =
  let inner input =
    let res = run p input in
    match res with
        | Ok (c, rest) -> Ok ((mapper c), rest)
        | fail         -> fail
  in (Parser inner)
```

`mapper` in this code has type `('a -> 'a)` but that's of no use since it's the whole purpose of the map to change from something to something else.
The explanation I gave myself about this behaviour is: "since `c` in `Ok (c, rest)` represents an `'a` then mapping it in `Ok ((mapper c), rest)` and putting it also in an `Ok` must mean that they are of the same type", if this is correct I'm confused about how to correct the types.

I'd like the type to be `('a -> 'b)` but I am unsure on how to achieve that, even if I write the types manually nothing changes.

These are the types involved

```ml
type 'a result =
  | Ok of 'a
  | Fail of string

type 'a parser = Parser of (char list -> ('a * char list) result)
```

I've made a small "proof of concept" and here the mapping function has the "right" type, so I'm really confused:

```ml
type 'a result =
  | Y of 'a
  | N

let mmap f = function
  | Y y -> let res = f y in Y res
  | N   -> N

let mapper o = [o]

let _ = mmap mapper (Y 1)
```

Let me know if you need something else, any explanation would help me a lot!

Comment: I've simplified the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77977046/figuring-out-why-these-types-differ-when-using-a-catch-all-in-the-pattern-matchi

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that `'a -> 'b` is not a valid type of any actual function. This says that the function can somehow produce a value of any type at all with no inputs of the type. The only functions of this type are those that don't actually return (such as `let rec g x = g x`).

Comment: @JeffreyScofield and Obj.magic, which is a function that makes any type pretend to be any other type. With all the breakage that can cause.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I'm not sure I've understood what you're saying, isn't the type of a "mapper" function `('a -> 'b)`? Receives an `'a`  and knows how to produce a `'b`. I'm not saying I'm right, I'm just confused and would like to know more.