# Figuring out why these types differ when using a catch all in the pattern matching

Tags: ocaml

I'd like some help with understanding how type inference affects the following code, which comes from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77976438/confused-about-how-to-change-the-type-of-a-function) (which after some thoughts I've simplified to the following):

```ml
type 'a result =
  | Succ of 'a
  | Fail

let first f = function
  | Succ c -> let res = f c in Succ res
  | fail   -> fail

let second f = function
  | Succ c -> let res = f c in Succ res
  | Fail   -> Fail
```

My question is: why does `f` in `first` have type `('a -> 'a)` but `f` in `second` have type `('a -> 'b)`?

You can see it [here](https://try.ocamlpro.com/?ref=paul-carletons-blog#code/type%27$,a%27result%27=!$5%27Succ%27of%27$,a!$5%27Fail!!!let%27first%27f%27r%27=!match%27r%27with!$5%27Succ%27c%27-$.%27let%27res%27=%27f%27c%27in%27Succ%27res!$5%27fail%27%27%27-$.%27fail!!let%27second%27f%27r%27=!match%27r%27with!$5%27Succ%27c%27-$.%27let%27res%27=%27f%27c%27in%27Succ%27res!$5%27Fail%27%27%27-$.%27Fail).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The two occurrences of `Fail` in `Fail -> Fail` in `second` are treated as two distinct values, and thus are allowed to have different types `'a result` and `'b result`, but
- The two occurrences of `fail` in `fail -> fail` in `first` are treated as the same value, and thus cannot change types.

Or at least the type inference system doesn't allow it to change types. I'm not sure whether that's a specification or a quirk of this particular interpreter.

As food for thought, a third version:

```ml
let third f r = match r with
  | Succ c -> Succ (f c)
  | _ -> r
```

You and I know that if we reach the `_` case of the pattern-match, it means that `r` is `Fail` and could be of any `'b result` type, but what the compiler sees is that `r` is of type `'a result` since it's the input, and so `'a == 'b`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there somewhere I could read about this?

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni Not that I know, but it does seem somewhat logical. The interpreter doesn't really check that `fail` can only take the form `Fail`; all it knows is that it's a value of type `'a result`.

Comment: Ok I've read your edit, makes sense

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni Because a function can have only one type. Imagine `function | Succ c -> c | Fail -> 12`; the compiler is going to say that this must have type `int result -> int` because `c` and `12` must have the same type.